# Using one limit to compute other

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I've calculated $\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{1^p+2^p+\cdots+n^p}{n^{p+1}}=\dfrac1{p+1}$ where $p\in\mathbb{N}$ fixed. I feel it should help me get this one $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\dfrac{1^p+2^p+\cdots+n^p}{n^{p}}-\dfrac{n}{p+1}\right)$, but I'm not sure how. Any hints?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know how to get the second limit by using the first one since $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\dfrac{1^p+2^p+\ldots+n^p}{n^{p}}-\dfrac{n}{p+1}\right) = \lim_{n\to\infty}n\left(\dfrac{1^p+2^p+\ldots+n^p}{n^{p+1}}-\dfrac{1}{p+1}\right)$$

which is of $0\times\infty$ type.

But both limits can be computed using  [Stolz–Cesàro theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem) through [binomial formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem)

Added:
\begin{align}
&\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\dfrac{1^p+2^p+\ldots+n^p}{n^{p}}-\dfrac{n}{p+1}\right)\\
=&\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\dfrac{(p+1)(1^p+2^p+\ldots+n^p)-n^{p+1}}{(p+1)n^{p}}\right) \\
=&\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\dfrac{(p+1)(n+1)^p-(n+1)^{p+1}+n^{p+1}}{(p+1)((n+1)^{p}-n^p)}\right)\\
=&\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\dfrac{\frac{(p+1)p}{2}n^{p-1}+\text{term of lower order}}{(p+1)pn^{p-1} + \text{term of lower order}}\right)\\
=& \frac{1}{2}
\end{align}

In the comment, @Hamou gives a way to get directly the limit by application of theorem on convergence rate of Riemann sum. For exact statement of the theorem, look into the reference therein.

Comment: Thanks! I used the theorem and then $p$ times L'Hospital and got the answer $\frac{1-n}{n}$. This however appears to be wrong, as the result is supposed to be $-\infty$, says Mathematica software.

Comment: @Klobbbyyy No, your limit is $-\dfrac{1}{2}$.

Comment: @Klobbbyyy I added some details

Comment: @Hamou Thank you! Just realized my mistake.

Comment: @LiuGang Could you please explain where did the fourth line came from?

Comment: @Klobbbyyy It's by binomial formula, see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem).

Comment: @LiuGang Solved, many thanks.

Comment: @LiuGang Everything is right until the last 2 equalities... You can see that the answer is $-\inf$

Comment: I've two remarks: the limit is negative and why the  $b_n$'s sequence is strictly monotone. If you try by using the approximate theorem of Riemann sum: On the subspace $\mathcal{C}^1([a,b])$ of continuously differentiable functions, we have

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=1}^{n} f\left(a+\frac{k}{n}(b-a)\right) - n\int_a^b f(x)\,dx = \frac{f(a) - f(b)}{2}.$$  here $a=0$ and $b=1$ and $f(x)=x^p$. we get the limit as $-\dfrac{1}{2}$.

Comment: @Hamou +1 for the theorem, but take $f=x, a=0, b = 1$ in your theorem to see the sign

Comment: @LiuGang Thank you for your remark, the formula is: $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} f\left(a+\frac{k}{n}(b-a)\right) - n\int_a^b f(x)\,dx = \frac{f(a) - f(b)}{2}.$$

Comment: @Hamou Could you give a reference for this theorem?

Comment: See page $478$ in this [Document](http://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/~rombaldi/Capes/AnalyseChap20.pdf).

Comment: @Hamou Thank you very much

Comment: @Hamou Could you please explain what's wrong with the calculation? Why doesn't the Stolz theorem work? $(p+1)n^p$ is strictly increasing and goes to $\infty$, as the theorem asks it to be.

Comment: @Klobbbyyy There's no problem with the calculation, see the Document given by Hamou, that's a different application.

Comment: @LiuGang But he claims the limit is $-\frac1{2}$, not $\frac1{2}$. I'm still a beginner, so please bear with me.

Comment: @Klobbbyyy that's for the limit of $\left(\dfrac{1^p+2^p+\ldots+(n-1)^p}{n^{p}}-\dfrac{n}{p+1}\right)$(which is your limit minus 1). Btw, Hamou's citation is not exact, look into his document for exact statement of the theorem.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Use the equivalence $1^p+2^p+\ldots+n^p\sim \dfrac{n^{p+1}}{p+1}$.
$$\dfrac{\sum_{k=1}^nk^p}{n^{p+1}}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\dfrac{k}{n}\right)^p=\frac{1-0}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n\left(0+\dfrac{k}{n}(1-0)\right)^p\to\int_0^1x^pdx=\dfrac{1}{p+1}$$

Comment: What does 'equivalence' mean in this context?

Comment: $u_n\sim v_n$ ($v_n\neq 0$)if $\dfrac{u_n}{v_n}\to 1$.

Comment: I have a problem with this. If I am to plug this in, I first have to break the limit down using limit laws. But to get to $1^p+2^p+\ldots+n^p$ in order to use the equivalence, I would have to pass through indeterminate forms like $\infty-\infty$.

Comment: The answer is edited.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't see how it solves the indeterminate form problem.